# Automatic map creation problem

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcpy, qgis-plugins, geopandas

I have two layers, first one is the ROAD layer and second one is the PARCEL layer (both polygon layers) as shown in Figure 1. I can get the data both in DXF and shapefile formats.

[image]

My task is to compute the area of intersection between ROAD and PARCEL layer, this is the easy part. I can compute intersection using QGIS or Geopandas easily. However, the difficult part is creating maps for each of the parcel. Sometimes, I have to create more then a hundred maps for each project. For mapping, there is a template that I have to use, which is similiar to the one shown in Figure 2. Also, some attribute data should be included in the map, such as owner of the parcel.

[image]

These maps should be in both PDF and DXF formats. Each map should be in A3 size. To be able to create such maps, what libraries or programming languages should I use? I have experience in GeoPandas library but I am not sure if it is enough for this task. Should I try QGIS plugin development or ArcPY? Could you share your experiences and ideas about this problem?

Comment: You could achieve this without developing anything. Using just QGIS Atlas. Your atlas iterator would be the whole parcels presenting intersections. You will also need a point layer from these parcels with the iterator id of the parcels. These parcels will need to have all the data you want to add in the layout (owner, area, intersection area)

Answer (score -1):

You can use pyqgis to automate such things.
Look at https://kartoza.com/en/blog/how-to-create-a-qgis-pdf-report-with-a-few-lines-of-python/ which was done using QGIS 2 series. You can easily adapt this to the Pyqgis 3 syntax.

For a gentle introduction to Pyqgis read https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis-101-exporting-layouts/

Or https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/